# Universal Windows App - Auto Startup

Tags: uwp

We have developed a Universal Windows App mainly focusing for Desktops.
We are able to install and run the app without any issue.

Now our client is asking for Auto Startup facility, whenever the machine is started or restarted, the app should run automatically.

We could not find an option for enabling the same while creating package.

Can you please suggest a solution for achieving the auto start up?

Comment: *"whenever the machine is started or restarted, the app should run automatically."* - You'd need a service for that. Unless you meant to say, that it should start whenever a user logs in. In that case you could create a scheduled task using the [Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614.aspx).

Comment: Take a Look @ [BackgroundTask](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask) Sample. Take a Look @ [Conditions for background tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks#conditions-for-background-tasks). You are looking for `SessionConnected`

Answer (score 5):

There is a workaround which allows you start the app during startup.

First you need to get a `*.lnk` shortcut to the app. This can be done by pinning the app to the Start Menu as a tile and then dragging and dropping the tile to a folder or to the Desktop. This will create a shortcut that can launch the app.

To run the app automatically after boot, you can just put it into the Startup folder: press `Win+R` and type `shell:startup`. Everything in this folder is automatically opened after boot. You can just drag and drop your `*.lnk` file in this folder and reboot to see how it works.

Comment: Again, this does not start the application on **reboot**. It starts the application, when that particular user who copied the shell link into their startup folder logs in. This is not what the question is asking for (although I'm also not sure, whether the question is really asking for what the OP needs).

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think it could better for you enable kiosk mode for your app here is the doc

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt633799(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Startup Task that executes your app when the user logs in.

See section "Start an executable file when users log into Windows" at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extensions#start-your-app-in-different-ways